# Command-line Decrypting of PDF, given a document open password

Tags: windows, command-line, pdf, encryption

I've been given a PDF that is password-protected. I have the document-open password, which is enough to decrypt the contents and allow PDF readers to load the content correctly.

Is there a command-line tool that will perform this decryption process (based on the provided password) and write the decrypted PDF to a new file?

Comment: Linux: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. [Qpdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/) should do what you want:

```
qpdf --password=thepassword --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf
```

You can find a download for Windows (assuming you have [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) installed) if you go to `Files->qpdf->latest version`, then scroll down to find a description of the files (you can find a link to version 5.11, the most recent version as of 2014-3-28, [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/qpdf/5.1.1/)).

[Choco](https://chocolatey.org) users can install the package by issuing `choco install qpdf` ([ref](https://chocolatey.org/packages/qpdf))

Comment: You don't have to install MinGW if you don't want to develop code for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdftk`'s command-line version ("[PDFtk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)"): (It is available for server platforms under a GPLv2 license)

```
pdftk "input filename.pdf" input_pw "password" output "output filename.pdf"
```